# Encountering "Missing targetObjectId with template" error when trying to send email template using Apex trigger

Tags: apex

Goal: Send an email template using Apex.

Error encountering:

> Error: There were custom validation error(s) encountered while saving
>   the affected record(s). The first validation error encountered was
>   "Apex trigger FilesAccountUpload_Tr caused an unexpected exception,
>   contact your administrator: FilesAccountUpload_Tr: execution of
>   BeforeInsert caused by: System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First
>   exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Missing
>   targetObjectId with template: []

Please suggest why is this error occurring.

Below is the code:

```
 if((programs[0].keyword__c).containsAny(Filename)){


            // if(filename.contains('visit')){
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

            // Step 2: Set list of people who should get the email
            List<String> sendTo = new List<String>();
            sendTo.add('harv@gmail.com');
            mail.setToAddresses(sendTo); 


            // Step 3: Set who the email is sent from
            mail.setReplyTo('harv@gmail.com');
            mail.setSenderDisplayName('File gets uploaded');

        /*    // (Optional) Set list of people who should be CC'ed
            List<String> ccTo = new List<String>();
            ccTo.add('harv@gmail.com');
            mail.setCcAddresses(ccTo); */

            // Step 4. Set email contents - you can use variables!
            EmailTemplate et = [SELECT id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE developerName = 'APVTemplate'];
            mail.setTemplateId(et.id);


            // Step 5. Add your email to the master list
            mails.add(mail);

            // Step 6: Send all emails in the master list
            Messaging.sendEmail(mails);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error, states, calling `setTargetObjectId()` is [mandatory when using a template](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_single.htm):

> `setTargetObjectId(targetObjectId)`  Required if using a template, optional otherwise. The ID of the contact, lead, or user to which the email will be sent. The ID you specify sets the context and ensures that merge fields in the template contain the correct data.

Comment: Understood but in this case, the recipient's email doesn't exist in the system. Can I still use the setTargetObjectId(targetObjectId) to add email address or should I actually create a user with this email address.

Comment: @user54028 You can't user `setTargetObjectId()` without a target object, which may be a Contact, Lead, or User - so you don't have to create a User as such.

Comment: I added the  mail.setTargetObjectId(c.Id); and commented out the sendTo list part from the above code and it worked.Thanks!